How to Position Carousel Arrows on Top and Prevent Lagging in React with @brainhubeu/react-carousel
I'm building a React component using @brainhubeu/react-carousel to display a list of services. I've successfully implemented the carousel with features like autoplay, infinite loop, and arrows. However, I'm facing an issue with the arrow positioning and performance.
I want the carousel arrows to be positioned on top of the carousel items, rather than on the sides. While I've achieved this using custom arrow components and functions, I've noticed a slight lag when scrolling between items. This lag is noticeable as a sort of "winking" effect.
I've tried two approaches:
1. Using the arrowsPlugin: This plugin automatically positions the arrows on the sides. While this is convenient, it doesn't allow for custom positioning.

        <ServicesContainer>
            <ServicesImage />
            <ServicesInnerSection>
                <ServicesColumnContainer>
                    <ServicesColumn>
                        <ServicesTitle>
                            <ServicesSubtitle>Nos services</ServicesSubtitle>
                            <ServicesTitleText>
                                Nous vous offrons des services sur-mesure
                            </ServicesTitleText>
                        </ServicesTitle>
                    </ServicesColumn>
                </ServicesColumnContainer>

                <SlidesContainer>
                    <Carousel
                        slides={services}
                        plugins={[
                            "clickToChange",
                            {
                                resolve: slidesToShowPlugin,
                                options: {
                                    numberOfSlides: 3,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                resolve: autoplayPlugin,
                                options: {
                                    interval: 5000,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                resolve: infinitePlugin,
                            },
                            {
                              resolve: arrowsPlugin,
                              options: {
                                addArrowClickHandler: true,
                                arrowLeft: (
                                  <ServicesArrowButton>
                                    <IoMdArrowBack />
                                  </ServicesArrowButton>
                                ),
                                arrowRight: (
                                  <ServicesArrowButton>
                                    <IoMdArrowForward />
                                  </ServicesArrowButton>
                                ),
                              },
                            },
                        ]}
                    />
                </SlidesContainer>
            </ServicesInnerSection>
        </ServicesContainer>

and this is how it looks like:
enter image description here
2. Custom Arrow Components: I've created custom arrow components and used functions to handle scrolling to the next and previous items. This provides more control over positioning but introduces the lag.
export function NosServices() {
  const services = [/*services list...*/];
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent((prevSlide) =>
      prevSlide === services.length - 1 ? 0 : prevSlide + 1
    );
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent((prevSlide) =>
      prevSlide === 0 ? services.length - 1 : prevSlide - 1
    );
  };

  return (
    <ServicesContainer>
      <ServicesImage />
      <ServicesInnerSection>
        <ServicesColumnContainer>
          <ServicesColumn>
            <ServicesTitle>
              <ServicesSubtitle>Nos services</ServicesSubtitle>
              <ServicesTitleText>
                Nous vous offrons des services sur-mesure
              </ServicesTitleText>
            </ServicesTitle>
          </ServicesColumn>
          <ServicesColumn>
            <ServicesArrowContainer>
              <ServicesArrowButton onClick={prevSlide}>
                <IoMdArrowBack />
              </ServicesArrowButton>
              <ServicesArrowButton onClick={nextSlide}>
                <IoMdArrowForward />
              </ServicesArrowButton>
            </ServicesArrowContainer>
          </ServicesColumn>
        </ServicesColumnContainer>

        <SlidesContainer>
          <Carousel
            value={current}
            onChange={setCurrent}
            slides={services}
            plugins={[
              "clickToChange",
              {
                resolve: slidesToShowPlugin,
                options: {
                  numberOfSlides: 3,
                },
              },
              {
                resolve: autoplayPlugin,
                options: {
                  interval: 5000,
                },
              },
              {
                resolve: infinitePlugin,
              },
            ]}
          />
        </SlidesContainer>
      </ServicesInnerSection>
    </ServicesContainer>
  );
};

and this is how it looks (and how I want it):
enter image description here
I'd like the carousel arrows to be positioned on top of the carousel items without any noticeable lag. I'm looking for a solution that maintains the smooth scrolling experience while achieving the desired arrow placement.
